# sed multiline match combined with delete between two lines?

Tags: awk, sed, multiline

Can I use sed's multiline match logic to delete all the lines between between a range of lines?

I have been trying all sorts of combinations of expressions with no luck.

Here is an example file ('creatures.txt'):

```
   START TAG
   species: swallowtail butterfly flying
   legs
   wings
   head
   END TAG
   START TAG
   species: common lizard running
   legs
   tail
   head
   END TAG
   START TAG
   species: peacock butterfly resting
   legs
   wings
   head
   END TAG
   START TAG
   species: blackbird flying
   legs
   wings
   head
   END TAG
```

I want do perform the following:

1. Whenever i encounter the following multiline match: (i) 'START' contained *somewhere* in the first line and (ii) 'butterfly' contained *somewhere* in the 2nd line
2. then delete all the lines between the 'START TAG' and 'END TAG' lines.

So using the example file above, the resulting output would be:

```
   START TAG
   END TAG
   START TAG
   species: common lizard
   legs
   tail
   head
   END TAG
   START TAG
   END TAG
   START TAG
   species: blackbird
   legs
   wings
   head
   END TAG
```

Thanks,
James.

Comment: Could you please wrap up your samples in code tags and let us know then as it is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
sed '/START TAG/{N;/butterfly/{:a;/END TAG/!{N;ba};d}}' file
```

Explanation:

```
# Enter block when 'START TAG' is found
/START TAG/ {
    N # Append next line to the pattern buffer
    # Enter block when 'butterfly' is found
    /butterfly/ {
        :a # Create a label (could be also :foo)
        # Enter block unless 'END TAG' is found
        /END TAG/! {
            N # Append next line to pattern buffer
            ba # branch back to label :a
        }
        # Once 'END TAG' is found
        d # Delete the pattern buffer
    }
}
```

PS: A slightly modified version can be used to keep the `START` / `END` tags:

```
sed '/START/{p;N;/butterfly/{:a;/END/!{N;ba};s/.*\n//}}' file
```

Comment: Since the OP said that the literal `butterfly` should appear on the line following the `START`, I would suggest `sed '/START/{n;/butterfly/{:a;N;/END/!ba;s/.*\n//}}' file`

Comment: hek2mgl, thankyou so much for this!
It works a treat!

Comment: @ClutchingatStraws neither of the scripts in the answer will produce the output you asked for (and imagine yourself having to debug or enhance them!). I suspect potong's script in the comment probably would produce the output you asked for but it'll be GNU sed specific and I have no idea if it'd robustly handle different input (it might be fine or it might summon the dark God Cthulhu for all I can tell) or how you'd enhance it later if you had to do anything slightly different (e.g. include a test for "wings" on the 4th line of each record). Just something to think about....

Answer (score 1):

Any time you find yourself saying `sed multiline` you are looking at the wrong tool. sed is for doing s/old/new on individual lines, that is all. For anything else you should be using awk.

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ rec = (rec=="" ? "" : rec ORS) $0 }
/END/ {
    numLines = split(rec,lines,ORS)
    print (lines[2] ~ /butterfly/ ? lines[1] ORS lines[numLines] : rec)
    rec = ""
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
   START TAG
   END TAG
   START TAG
   species: common lizard running
   legs
   tail
   head
   END TAG
   START TAG
   END TAG
   START TAG
   species: blackbird flying
   legs
   wings
   head
   END TAG
```

The above will work using any awk in any shell on any UNIX box, is clear, simple, robust and easily modified if/when your requirements change later to look at or print any of the other lines in each record or any combinations of values in each line or across the whole record. For example, to generate a CSV of just records where the creature has wings:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ rec = (rec=="" ? "" : rec ORS) $0 }
/END/ {
    numLines = split(rec,lines,ORS)
    if ( lines[4] == "wings" ) {
        sub(/species: /,"",lines[2])
        for (i=2; i<numLines; i++) {
            printf "%s%s", lines[i], (i<(numLines-1) ? "," : ORS)
        }
    }
    rec = ""
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
swallowtail butterfly flying,legs,wings,head
peacock butterfly resting,legs,wings,head
blackbird flying,legs,wings,head
```

and anything else you might want to do is equally trivial and consistent.

Comment: Ed, many thanks. I really appreciate the code extract you have provided. I take your point too that i should use Awk.

Comment: @EdMorton I left the awk answer - by intention - for you :)

Comment: @ClutchingatStraws I agree that you should use awk.